# diagonal map on exterior algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, exterior-algebra, pfaffian

Let $F$ be a free module of rank $2m$ over a commutative ring $R$. In Buchsbaum-Eisenbud's paper from 1977 about structure theorems for free resolutions of ideals of codimension 3, they give a proof that the determinant of a $2m \times 2m$ alternating matrix is some polynomial squared. That polynomial is called the *pfaffian*. Their proof uses multilinear algebra, and I cannot figure it out, and I think my problem comes down to their use of the action of $\wedge F$ on $\wedge F^*$, where $F^* = \text{Hom}_R(F,R)$ is the dual of $F$.

They start the appendix by saying there is a map $\Delta: \wedge F \to \wedge F \otimes \wedge F$ which is induced by the map $\Delta(a) = a\otimes 1 + 1\otimes a \in \wedge F \otimes \wedge F$, for $a\in F$, and such that $\Delta$ is an algebra homomorphism.

My question is, how does this induce the desired $\Delta$? That is, what is $\Delta(a\wedge b)$ for $a,b\in F$? And if $\alpha\in \wedge^{2m} F$, then what is the component of $\Delta(\alpha)$ in $\wedge^{2m} F \otimes \wedge^0 F$? (I need this last part to calculate the divided power).

Comment: I think this depends on your definition of the tensor product of algebras; are you assuming this is the "super" tensor product where you have to insert signs in a suitable way?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown To be honest I am not sure, and I do not see that explained in the paper I mentioned above. However, the "super" tensor product you speak of makes the most sense to me, since they are classifying free resolutions (so you need to have appropriate signs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the relevant tensor product here is the super tensor product; if $A$ and $B$ are two superalgebras then their super tensor product has multiplication given on homogeneous elements by

$$(a_1 \otimes b_1)(a_2 \otimes b_2) = (-1)^{|b_1| |a_2|} a_1 a_2 \otimes b_1 b_2$$

which has a sign owing to the need to swap $b_1$ and $a_2$. One desirable feature of this definition is that it gives a natural isomorphism $\Lambda(V \oplus W) \cong \Lambda(V) \otimes \Lambda(W)$.

As you say, $\Delta$ is defined by the condition that it is an algebra homomorphism, and consequently (I will omit the wedges for readability)

$$\Delta(ab) = \Delta(a) \Delta(b) = (a \otimes 1)(b \otimes 1) + (a \otimes 1)(1 \otimes b) + (1 \otimes a)(b \otimes 1) + (1 \otimes a)(1 \otimes b)$$

(the point of writing all those out was to be very careful about signs), which simplifies to

$$\Delta(ab) = ab \otimes 1 + a \otimes b - b \otimes a + 1 \otimes ab.$$

If we write $\alpha \in \Lambda^{2m} F$ as a product $e_1 \dots e_{2m}$ where $e_i$ is a basis of $F$ (again omitting wedges), then $\Delta(\alpha)$ is a product of terms of the form $(e_i \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes e_i)$, and consequently the component in $\Delta^{2m} F \otimes \Delta^0 F$ is just $\alpha$ again.